# Binding "true or false" as a PDO parameter

Tags: php, pdo

I have a MySQL column 'public' that contains boolean values (aka tinyint, 1 or 0). When querying I generally don't care about the value of the public column, so by default I pass an underscore (MySQL wildcard). In some instances though I only want rows that match "public = 0" or "public = 1" so I override the underscore with either 0 or 1. That's not the clearest explanation I've ever given so here's some code:

```
public function get_hunts($public = '_') {
  $sth = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hunts WHERE( user_id = :user AND public = :public)");
  $sth->bindParam(':user', $this->_id);
  $sth->bindParam(':public', $public);
  $sth->execute();
  $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $result;
}

//get any result
get_results();

//get only public results
get_hunts(1)
```

Binding an underscore (I've also tried the general wildcard %) in this way causes the query to fail. What is a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use any wildcard characters, you'd need to use a `LIKE` comparison instead of an equals

```
AND public LIKE :public
```

Otherwise, you'd need to take some kind of *query builder* approach where you build up the `WHERE` conditions based on arguments to your function.

```
public function get_hunts($public = null) {
    $where = array(
        'user_id = :user'
    );
    $params = array(
        ':user' => $this->_id
    );

    if (null !== $public) {
        $where[] = 'public = :public';
        $params[':public'] = (boolean) $public;
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM hunts WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($params); // same as binding

    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind parameters are only for *simple literals*, so you cannot bind things like table and column names (identifiers) or `IN` clauses (lists of literals).

So what you want is not possible in a straightforward manner.

What you really should do is use a different query:

```php
function get_hunts($public=null) {
    // assuming hunts.public is defined as NOT NULL
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hunts WHERE user_id=:user";
    if ($public!==null) {
       $sql .= ' AND public=:public';
    }
    $sth  = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':user', $this->_id);
    if ($public!==null) {
        $sth->bindParam(':public', $public, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

If you really don't want to use a different query, you can use a hacky solution with a `CASE` expression.

```sql
SELECT * FROM hunts WHERE user_id=:user
  AND public=
    CASE :public WHEN 0 THEN 0 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE public END
```

If the value you bind is not 0 or 1, the `WHERE` condition will require `public` to be equal to itself and thus always true. Otherwise the value of `:public` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out answer. For now I've just swapped out "public = :public" for "public LIKE :public" as Phil suggested, allowing me to use a wildcard; purely because it was a quick and simple fix. Both your answer and Phil's longer alternative are probably better solutions though, so I've learnt something.

Comment: +1 Nice use of `CASE` :). FYI, your second `:user` binding should be `:public`

Comment: @MartinAnsty it wasn't suggested. and you choose wrong solution out of laziness and ignorance

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I clearly said "_for now_"; a quick and dirty one word fix. I noted that the query builder approach was the correct solution and have since implemented Phil's code. I find it somewhat unfair for you to down vote the question based on the (temporary) actions I took afterwards, but if that's what makes you happy...